# Teradata Hadoop Connector using split by amp

Tags: teradata, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using TDCH for pulling data from Teradata to  hadoop cluster using TDCH.
In TDCH i am using split by amp option .I have 120 amp Teradata System and in my TDCH script i am defining 30 mappers. So each will pull data from 4 AMP .I am getting like below queries :-

```
'Select "NAME" ,"ADRESS" FROM FROM tdampcopy(ON "TABLENAME" USING AMPList(136,137,138,139)) AS THCALIAS1 .
```

It is creating 30 queries with 30 session ids. When they are running it on Teradata System , it is causing skewness as in each query only 4 amps are invloved and DBAs are killing these queries. Any pointers to how we can overcome with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `split.by.hash`, as for using `split.by.amp` you would need a table which is well distributed with low skewness. In case in your table the data is not well distributed among all the AMPs, the performance will be impacted drastically.

`Split.by.hash` should resolve this for you.

Comment: Why would Teradata not localize the tasks involved in the generated queries?  I explained a query using the TDAMPCOPY UDF and all the steps are ALL AMP: